# Do descriptions of what exist map to causes recognized by Man? Can we describe coherent models for broad patterns of knowledge?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, ontology, causation, intersubjectivity

**EDIT 0** - To clarify, in the table below, the term **God** would be missing from it's provisional box for humans who map ultimate causes exclusively to non-moral, aka natural, types of cause. Sigmund Freud, who describes himself as a godless Jew, maps ultimate causes to unknown attributes of external reality and to the unknown attributes of the biological unconscious (the It), and he maps proximate causes to the conscious biological ego. In Freud's description a source of cause is unknown (unconscious) until it becomes conscious to the ego. Humanity now maps sources of cause to the abstract unconscious and/or to the natural biological unconscious. In Freud's model when the ego interacts with reality the superego forms by storing moral memories of human interactions in the unconscious ego. Psychoanalytic conflicts are said to occur between the intentions of the conscious ego and interference from the unconscious id or the unconscious superego memories. The table is a provisional map of expressed ideas of humans and does not try to preference any particular type of cause.

**EDIT 1** - I changed the term in the chart below from **psychic** to **psychogenic** (but all the distinctions in my chart seem to be psychogenic in origin):

| TYPES OF CAUSE | Ultimate | Proximate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Moral** | God | Man |
| **Natural** | Reality | Nature |
| **Psychogenic** | Unconscious | Conscious |

My question relates primarily to the term **Psychogenic** in the chart above. Does anyone think there exists a better, or more compelling, term for the distinction between unconscious and conscious? Beyond that constructive comments or criticisms might help me develop a more coherent descriptive model.

This model revolves around Man as the proximate moral cause wherein Man recognizes all the other terms in the model. In legal analysis Man recognizes distinctions between an ultimate (remote) and proximate (nearby) cause; between a moral (human) and natural cause; and between a sole or joint cause. Since ancient times acts of God under the law refer to all natural events not caused by the will of Man. The law cuts off Man's chain of reasoning back to an ultimate cause and deals only with Man's recognition of proximate causes.

In cognitive science and expert systems Man recognizes a distinction between vague and crisp sets but that distinction does not map neatly into Types of Cause. A sole cause would be one single cause. A joint cause would be two or more causes in combination. A fuzzy cause would be two or more types of cause operating as joint cause. I hold that the boxes in the map are inherently vague, fuzzy, and uncertain rather than crisp or certain classifications of Man's knowledge.

**EDIT 2 - Panpsychism** is inherent in the table above with the assumptions that the distinction between a moral and natural source of cause can be fuzzy, vague, or indistinct within human efforts to reason; and that the proximate sources of cause are the only means to map attributes to any abstract ultimate source of cause. Then some humans would form the belief in panpsychism due to their subjective experience of psychogenesis. Spinoza has been associated with so-called panpsychism: https://philarchive.org/archive/LINSP-4 *Spinoza thinks that there is only one fundamental being or substance, which he identifies with God or Nature. That is, Spinoza naturalizes God or, alternatively, deifies nature.*

Sigmund Freud, the founder of psychoanalysis, argues that the **psyche** is a biological feature of Man's body. Together the unconscious id (biological inner drives) and the conscious ego (effort to govern action in the sensory context) comprise the psyche. When the newborn ego interacts with external reality, the sensory context is that of the child interacting with a superior external ego, and the memories of interaction form what Freud calls the superego domain of the ego. Then the developing psyche has three elements: id, ego, superego. All this description maps to proximate moral or natural causes in my table except for the unconscious.

The ego is partly conscious and partly unconscious and becomes conscious of impulses arriving from the id which are otherwise unconscious. Freud's description of id, ego, superego, and external reality are called the structural model of the psyche. When he adds the distinction between the unconscious and conscious attributes it is called the topological model of the psyche. I think Freud only uses language of natural things to try to explain the emergence of Man's moral sentiments but to do so he must make use of Man's innate and inherent moral sense!

I think the idea of the Unconscious is similar to an ultimate source of cause such as God or Reality. Any of the three terms could apply in the model for whatever is abstract ultimate source of cause to Man. The respective terms map to proximate or known attributes in the mind of Man and not to the abstract unknown mysterious ultimate source of cause.

Comment: The purpose of your table remains unclear. What is its purpose, which philosophical problem does it help to solve? - As we know from psychology and neurology, there exist conscious and unconscious mental pocesses. Hence "psychic" cannot mark the border.

Comment: The purpose of the table is to explicate how the human mind works with broad general distinctions. In this context I map physics, chemistry, biology,  neurology, and some of medicine to the recognition of the natural type of cause arising in the minds of (moral) man. The distinction between the conscious and the unconscious becomes conscious in the mind of moral man. But it does not coherently map (relate) to the proximate moral or natural sources of cause. There is no inherent moral or natural content to the distinction between conscious and unconscious. Psychic fits better than neurological.

Comment: While this is an interesting reflection, you need articulate a question more definitively. Yes, I could give some pointers to *Is there a better, or more compelling, term for the distinction between unconscious and conscious?* But first one needs to understand what really you're asking. For better or worse, on SE sites *Constructive comments or criticisms might help me develop a more coherent descriptive model* will tend to invite closure as "opinion based"

Comment: @Rushi Thanks for comment concerning one motivation to close this question. I come from patent drafting background where the inventor of a new and useful device is expected to also choose terms in the patent claims that attempt to describe the elements and limitations that must be present in infringing articles.  Courts hold that the inventor can be their own lexicographer. The terms unconscious and conscious map to ancient Latin roots and are commonly used. So are the terms moral and natural. God, Reality, and the Unconscious are not often related to distinctions based on types of causes.

Comment: Everyone is a spiritual dualist — even the nuts like Dennett who would deny it. After all everyone admits that they exist.  Also everyone (nearly) goes to doctors, uses equipment (eg phones/computers), lives in modern civilized (more or less) society that is founded on materialistic accoutrements.  So in practice everyone needs to dance between two worldviews

Comment: This is called [Alaya consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses) aka Adana consciousness in the ancient Yogacara school, which means all the subconsciousness that is non layered and simultaneously makes patterns of habit that flow on in torrents...

Comment: Seems to me that if we include a god then we should include a tag such as "Theology" or "Christianity" in the tag list, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

**Your question is probing the problem that under physicalism, neither psyche nor morality are causal.**  This leads to the denial of free will by most physicalists, and also two ways to conclude that morality is -- irrelevant.

The first path is by denial of choice (determinism), hence the lack of any point to judging morality either when one is acting, or when evaluating an act after the fact.  The second path to denying morality is that it is an abstract thing, and physicalism HAS no abstract things in it (morality has no mass nor energy nor location).

So yes, one will need a different ontology than physicalism to arrive at selfhood, agency, and morality.

**There are two ways that naturalist leaning philosophers have approached this.**

**The first** is to realize that physics is not limited to "matter", but that information is also central to it. If one can extrapolate selfhood from algorithms, or information processing, then one can postulate some relation between this information/selfhood and causation on matter (information is intrinsic to physics after all).  Information is also an abstraction, so values are also plausibly related to information.  If one can show that physics is causally open (as QM shows, and chaos theory allows to leverage up to our macro world), then these more broadminded physicalists can build a story where selfhood and morality matter.

**The second method** to get to selfhood and agency used by near-physicalists is strong emergence.  We know that material structures and phenomena can emerge in surprising ways from simple substrates.  One can extrapolate that consciousness and selfhood are emergent phenomena, and sociology, then values/morality can be higher tiers of emergence off of consciousness.   IF one accepts downward causation from emergent structures onto a physical substrate, then tiered strong emergence gives a method to get to an ontology where selfhood and morality are causal. Here is an ambitious model of strong tiered emergence  https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/theory-knowledge/201702/psychologys-grand-unified-theory

**An alternative model is that of Karl Popper.**  Popper is a triplest.  He holds that the world consists of three different planes, that he calls worlds 1, 2 and 3.    Here is his summary of it:  https://tannerlectures.utah.edu/_resources/documents/a-to-z/p/popper80.pdf  Popper assumes the pre-existence of worlds 1 and 3, then world 2 emerges (using strong emergence) from world 1.  Popper is a "dualist" but not a spiritual dualist.

Morality is not a big feature of Popper's world 3.  If you want morality to be central, you will need a somewhat different version of ontological triplism.  And as you seem to be a spiritual dualist, you will need world 2 to be pre-existing not emergent.  Popper could be a useful reference for you in building a spiritual triplest ontological model.  **A spiritual dualist version of Popper's three worlds could support your three levels of causation.**

Comment: This is a very useful answer. The reason I take morality to be central is not that I think it is more compelling than physicalism, but rather, physicalism cannot abstract away from distinctions arising in the minds of man as the source of natural concepts. Philosophers and scientists express what I call conscious modes of self-other communication. Helmholtz argues that 2D perceptions in the visual field map to 3D position and speed of objects as if generated by conscious inference but the inference is unconscious. The distinctions in my table seem to arise by Unconscious Inference: a mystery!

Comment: @SystemTheory -- As an aside, do not be embarrassed about the poor opinion held by most philosophers of spiritual dualists.  I treat it as a challenge.  I have fully integrated spiritual dualism into methodological naturalism, and I consider spiritual dualism to be more compatible with the methodology than physicalism is.  And yes, I have adapted Popper's 3 worlds ontology.  There is a reason I understood what you were asking about ...

Comment: Thanks for link to Popper's paper on the three worlds. I studied electrical engineering and intellectual property law but became more of an applied philosopher. Popper maps physical objects to world 1. These would be tangible infringing articles or artistic expressions that infringe intangible novel, useful, and non-obvious elements described in utility patents; or intangible features of copyright, trade dress (trademark), and design patent infringement analysis. Popper maps intangibles to World 3 and tangibles to World 1. To me distinctions (between worlds) originate as psychogenic knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested tabular map of fundamental categories of cause doesn't seem to map to your headline question about knowledge in any obvious way, but that could be my inability to make sense of your words. The 'map' seems to demand answers to the following questions:

Why have you defined God as the ultimate moral cause? That rather presupposes that there is a God, which some people might consider to invalidate your map from the get-go.

Why do you consider psychogenic causes to be a separate category, rather than a subset of natural causes? Are you saying that mental causes are not natural and not real? Do you consider that row of the tabular map to be exclusively about human psychogenic causes, or are you admitting any entity which has some level of consciousness? And presumably, if there are any panpsychists in the house, they might tell you that everything has to be admitted, so we are back with the last two rows of the table being indistinguishable.

If you say that the final row of your table is intended only to consider human consciousness, then how do you square that with evolution? At what point as we wind back the video of evolution does primitive hominid consciousness cease to be included in the row? At the very least you have a definition problem.

I could go on, but really I can summarise my views by saying that attempting to summarise the endlessly multi-faceted complexity of the Universe with nine ill-defined terms is possibly a little simplistic.

Comment: All terms evoke semantic uncertainty. God, Reality, and Unconscious are terms that evoke an abstract ultimate (source of) cause. The distinction between God and Reality in human discourse seems to me that God has moral attributes in addition to being an abstract source of cause.  The assumption that the ultimate source of cause has only natural attributes generates the term Reality in human discourse. In psychoanalysis there is only the conscious ego and unconscious reality until the ego becomes conscious of reality and biological impulses. The Unconscious is thus ultimate like God or Reality.