Is it impossible to physically observe whether an action is voluntary (purposeful)?
For example you can observe a rock rolling down a hill and we know this action is not a purposeful or voluntary because the rock has no ability to make willful decisions about its movement.
We can observe a human raising their arm. However what we actually observe is the arm moving, just like the rock, correct? We have no way to observe whether there was a willful decision made.
Therefore if we cannot physically observe if some action has a willful decision made behind it, how can we know the movement was voluntary, or purposeful, or a decision, or a choice, etc., if all we can observe is the movement?

Presumably there exist today sufficiently sophisticated techniques for applying suitable external electrical stimulus to the brain to cause pretty much any desired motor response. And such motor behavior would be the will of them who externally apply the stimulus rather than of the patient to whom they apply it. But a third-party observer unaware that any external stimulation was happening would have no reason to imagine that it was.

Apocryphal: I was walking across an empty country road at a bend, when I broke into a run. I then consciously heard the car and it came into view, but I realised that my body had reacted to the sound at a level below my consciousness. I observed that it was not a voluntary action, but instinctive reaction.

It's far more likely that the rock started moving on its own than an iPhone should randomly come into being. Just saying...

I would call this a False Equivalence.

Can you tell the difference between a sleepwalker and a purposeful walker?

A purpose implies a conscious subject that can have intentions. Why not go a step further and question the existence of such conscious subjects as well? I'm just saying, this question seems to stop midway on the road to solipsism.

This is an 18 page paper describing how the law treats states of mind and voluntary or involuntary actions in the more modern context.  A Mind to Blame: New Views
on Involuntary Acts Deborah W. Denno, J.D., Ph.D.
http://www.antoniocasella.eu/archipsy/Denno_2003.pdf. The law is not uniform in its use of terms or doctrines because it is a distributed intelligence system like any other institution in a human social group. In terms of philosophy the law incorporates folk psychology and at the same time it is an expression of folk psychology in action within society. We do "mind reading!"

The example is a bit flawed in that the rock is not the source of the energy that moves it, whereas the human arm is. This already makes a significant distinction between who the agents is in both examples, before we even get to the "what is free will" question that you're trying to get to.

However valid the Question might be by assumption, will you please go back and correct '… this action is not a purposeful or voluntary…'? Until you correct that, what's the point?

This question is unanswerable and so it has no meaning. For one thing
I wonder if the posting of this question was

It may not be impossible but it certainly can't be done reliably. It's common knowledge in engineering that you can reverse engineer to determine function but not design intent.

We can infer whether an action is purposeful by "taking the Intentional Stance": can we see a consciously realizable purpose to something that happened? Can we make a prediction of a voluntary action and see if the supposed actor does that?
If a person moves their arm, gets a cigarette, lights it and starts smoking, it is possible that it is a non-voluntary, 'sleepwalking' or habitual action in this case, but overall it must have been voluntary on their part in the past to develop such a complex sequence of actions. If you see someone in a hospital bed who can't speak move their arm, and you hold up a pack of cigarettes and they reach for it, it seems overwhelmingly likely that they are conscious and intending to do that. Does an intention make sense and allow for a prediction?
If you see an infant and their arms and legs are waving around randomly, you could say it is like a rock rolling downhill, but a better answer is that the baby wants something but doesn't yet know how to control their limbs. If you put a desired object in the baby's hand and it grasps and begins looking at it, intention makes sense there.
What intentions can we ascribe to rocks which would not be predicted adequately by gravity and strength of materials? None.
So the Intentional Stance helps to distinguish these cases. I forget who came up with the idea, but I remember a quote: "Brentano's Thesis - intentionality is the hallmark of the mental."

Daniel Dennett, but I'm pretty sure you knew that...;)

So the moment we will be able to predict human behavior it will become involuntary? Don't you thing it is strange that abilities of observer define properties of observable?

@Talex Under dualism, one could describe actions as fully predictable based on non-physical (albeit, nonphysical that is observed physically) as still being intentional without contradicting this answer.

@talex we can predict the movements of rocks with physics and the movements of people and animals with the Intentional Stance, but predictability has nothing to do with an action being involuntary. If human actions weren't somewhat predictable, we would not have a society, let alone an internet and forums like this one. I predicted that at least one person would downvote my answer.

Comment 1. Looks like Daniel Dennet coined intentional stance.  Reinvigorating Actus Reus: The Case for Involuntary Actions by Veterans with Post-Traumatic
Stress Disorder - Melissa Hamilton. Criminal culpability rests on ... the defendant’s state of mind, or mens rea, and a voluntary act, or actus reus. [I]n criminal cases ... rarely is there much focus on the existence of actus reus. This remains true
despite the fundamental principle of criminal law that “the general
doctrine of the voluntary act” means that “liability requires that the activity in question be voluntary.”

Comment 2. In ancient law actus reas is the requirement that the relevant action undertaken in a criminal prosecution or tort claim be voluntary action. The jury or judge as Trier of Fact in a case must determine both mens rea (guilty mind) and actus reas (voluntary action).  People who intend to kill or harm other people have a rational plan rooted in prudence: the ability to govern action by the use of reason. A child prior to age seven cannot reason like an adult and cannot have guilty mind or act with negligence. If we fail to punish intentional or negligent harm it will proliferate.

@ScottRowe - Curbing liberty to interact is coercive punishment. If you want to do a deep dive into human cognition as the basis of law then I suggest you read two publications by my law professor, Hugh Gibbons. Justifying Law is available here: https://www.biologyoflaw.org/Downloads/index.htm. Purpose of Law is available here: https://www.biologyoflaw.org/Purpose/index.htm. I influenced Hugh's thoughts on what it means to be a person under the law wherein others are implicit subjects like the self and not objects with explicit code or no implicit will. Also, the inner experience of freedom.

@ScottRowe but in your answer you distinguish voluntarily/involuntarily actions based on subjective factors (ability to predict and "making sense"(sic)). It basically means that this property is subjective. What one person see as voluntarily action another will perceive as involuntarily.

@talex as best I know, everything is subjective.

@ScottRowe while solipsism is technically valid position I find it counterproductive.

@talex to me, solipsism is the opposite of subjectivity.

@ScottRowe looks like we stuck in definition warzone :) No happiness live there.

@ScottRowe - In law, economics, and accounting a formal bargain, contract, or transaction between two agents is a bilateral agreement. Hugh Gibbons, economist turned lawyer, regards property & contracts as efforts to respect the will of each person. Economists argue markets (deals) are economically efficient (psychological efficiency?). Contracts can be for third party beneficiaries. Fiduciary obligations involve the highest degree of faith and loyalty. Principals employ agents causing agency problems. The public good does not manifest from pure bilateral agreements. So: cooperation problems!

@ScottRowe - Sigmund Freud wrote a famous book Civilization and Its Discontents. This is the book where Freud argues that a rational ego (biological effort to govern action) strives to become happy and remain so in the social world. He argues that failure to work in cooperation with others produces suffering. Nature threatens to make the ego suffer from the outside due its superior power and from the inside due to biological limitations. A rational ego strives to love and work. Yet social values of life, liberty, and pursuit of happiness also produce conflict, strife, and unhappiness. Why?

@SystemTheory because people are not sufficiently self-aware.

@ScottRowe - As I recall Sigmund Freud argues that unhappiness is caused by socialization (parents civilizing the child) and/or innate biological aggression. Abolishing rights to private property, for example, does not eliminate socialization drama or aggression that drive symbolic status games in the socialist or communist civilization. Adults who become more self-aware might conclude that Satan is the Lord of this world; or this world has attributes of Maya (illusion). Spinoza says affect is desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. Self & others cause mixed feelings.

@talex You write "So the moment we will be able to predict human behavior".. - but there's nothing that ensures we'll ever get there. Also, if we take a leaf out of Popper's book so to speak, even the best theory can never prove that a natural phenomenon is a certain way. Maybe in the future we'll be able to predict better what human beings do for example, because we'll also become very good at brainwashing them? This doesn't mean we have really disproved the possibility of independent/voluntary action as such.

@Amit I don't try to disprove voluntary actions exist. I'm just saying that  it's unfalsifiable claim.

@talex I don't quite see how that point was made in the comment I responded to. But anyway I agree, it will remain unfalsifiable as long as we can't define precisely what is meant by "voluntary","will","choice", and all the other words we use to distinguish ourselves from automatons :)

No, this is impossible.
This is exactly the reason why the question of whether we possess free will is still an open question. If we could distinguish between a non-voluntary action and a voluntary one, we could prove the existence of free will.
Free will advocates will argue that humans are agents that show voluntary actions.
Free will skeptics will argue that humans show no such thing.

I'm guessing that free-will skeptics behave just like we would expect people with free will to behave. Now, if they didn't, their case would be stronger. So, if they want to make their case, they should...

Free will advocates will report the existence of free will; and further report that such report is voluntary. Free will skeptics will report the non-existence of free will; and further report that all such reports are involuntary?

@SystemTheory  Involuntary is sometimes used with the meaning of against one's will. That's why I used the term non-voluntary.

@Philomath - So the free will skeptic argues that all actions and reports, by the advocate and skeptic of free will, are non-voluntary actions? Both act from compulsion?

@SystemTheory  Yes, I have no choice but to confirm this.  ;)

Most really seem not to want to believe that what they did, they were going to do anyway no matter how much one rewinds and replays history, and most really seem to hate the suggestion that anyone comes in "types", such as the type to subjectively feel like they have free will. +1.

You can ask the person whether they willed their arm to move or not and then make the reasonable induction based on the person's reply. Same way you observe whether paint is fluorescent: transmit a signal at it and see what kind of signal comes back.

What about people who cannot communicate with you? You have no way to know if their actions are voluntary? What about proto-humans like homo-erectus or Neanderthals? How do you know if animals do or do not perform voluntary action? Your test has significant restrictions and only works under very restrictive conditions. Are you saying there is no way to know outside of these conditions? How do you know the rock's actions are not voluntary or purposeful?

@Henry, you could ask them to raise their arm again if they meant to raise it, and not raise it if they didn't mean to.

@MichaelHall And what if they don't speak the same language as you? What if they came from a time machine and speak an extinct language? What if they are deaf? What if they are a proto-human? What if they are an alien? The test is only limited to those beings who can communicate with you. Is it impossible to know outside of those who can communicate with you?

@henry try categorizing culture and language as tools

Then you simply use your best judgement depending on the circumstances.  For example, if they stepped out of the time machine and immediately started having random, jerky, seizure like movements it might be reasonable to presume some sort of involuntary side effect of the time travel.  If instead they walk smoothly and deliberately over to a tree, reach up to pluck a fruit which they proceed to eat, it's reasonable to presume the action was voluntary.  What sort of answer are you looking for?

@MichaelHall "What sort of answer are you looking for?" I don't know. I don't have anything in mind. All I am saying is that the test only applies to a small sample of circumstances. Therefore this test seems like a bad test since it seems there are many circumstances it would not help us. Therefore I was pointing out the shortcomings of this answer.
"it's reasonable to presume" - a presumption is not knowledge. Therefore this doesn't seem like an answer as well

I think the test proposed in this answer would be sufficient in a solid majority of occasions.  Time travelers speaking extinct languages notwithstanding...

@MichaelHall "solid majority of occasions" - so basically you are saying outside of these occasions it is impossible to know. Correct?

Please re-read my earlier comment on judgement and circumstances.

@MichaelHall I literally addressed your earlier comment Michael. You used the word "presumption". Are you saying presumptions are the same as knowledge?

No, I am not saying that at all, but reasonable presumptions help us make sense of the world around us so we don't live in a state of constant confusion.

@MichaelHall I have nothing against presumptions. I use presumption all the time in my life. I just don't categorize them as knowledge. Therefore according to your logic, outside of communication, its not possible to have any knowledge about whether an action is [volitional, purposeful, voluntary, intentional, a choice, a decision]. Why can't you embrace your own position?

I fully embrace my position, but I often conceal it to facilitate drawing out salient points. This is philosophy, nobody really knows anything with absolute certainty. Even with communication you cannot know whether their actions are voluntary or not. They could be lying, or not have free will.  Question: Does "knowing" that someone's arm motion was voluntary really change anything?

No, it turns out that people’s after-the-fact beliefs—no matter how sincerely and fervently they are held—are unreliable. Our minds do a whole lot of confabulating. Totally healthy and normal people make up explanations aimed at minimizing perceived incongruities. And we are entirely unaware that we’re doing so.

Part of this depends on how certain words are defined. Most specifically, it depends on how you define the word "know". If you are asking for absolute certainty, it is impossible to know with certainty.
We have to get into all of the standard questions about whether what you are perceiving is real in the first place or some form of hallucination, it is conceivable that the person is a philosophical zombie incapable of willing anything or doing anything at all purposefully, etc. But even setting those aside, and assuming that the world is essentially the way it seems, its still impossible to know what is in someone else's head.
We also need to define "voluntary" and "purposeful". This seems obvious in most cases, but there are edge cases that might need to be addressed. If I do something purely out of reflex, is it voluntary and purposeful? If you throw a ball at me, there is a good chance I will try to catch it reflexively without any forethought or any intention about what I do if I catch it. Does that fit voluntary and purposeful for your purposes?
Also, what if I'm doing something purely by habit? I virtually always brush my teeth immediately after a shower. There have been times if I get dirty that I've taken showers immediately before supper and regretted brushing my teeth as soon as I did it, but I acted out of habit. This was certainly voluntary in the sense that nothing forced me to do it, and it was a complex action not a muscle twitch. But at the same time, it probably wasn't purposeful and if I had been giving it any thought, I wouldn't have done it.
But, once we nail down our definitions of "voluntary" and "purposeful" and if we accept "supported by reasonably sufficient evidence" as a definition of "know", then we can get at least a decent idea as to whether something was purposeful by looking at the evidence. For one obvious thing, we can just ask the person. Now, people can and do lie about exactly that all the time. It comes up in Court all the time. But, if the person does not have a compelling reason to lie in either direction, then we can probably trust what they say. We can also look at whether the person was likely to want the probable results. If so, it was probably purposeful, if not it probably wasn't. This isn't always decisive by itself of course, but it goes a very long way. A complex series of actions is probably at least intentional in the sense of not being a random twitch (though it could still be a reflex or habit), whereas a single small motion might easily be a twitch or entirely involuntary action. Coughing is usually involuntary by contrast.

Lieing would probably be something that must be conscious and voluntary, so get people to lie and you have your answer: not a P-zombie or sleepwalker.

We must make the distinction between 'observation' and 'theoretical inference'. We can observe a rock rolling down a hill, but we can't observe gravity; 'gravity' is a theoretical inference we make after we observe rocks rolling down hills.
When we observe human behaviors, the first thing we have to note is that they are (generally speaking) locally anti-entropic. We pick up a cup; we gather things together; we throw a ball; we walk across a room… Physical objects (including human bodies) that would normally remain at rest via Newton's first law don't remain at rest. This implies the application of a force. Further, this movement is complexly anti-entropic. For instance, we don't merely move pieces of wood around randomly; we shape them and fix them together to make tables, chairs, cabinets, etc, and then apply these constructed objects in further (locally) anti-entropic ways. These observations can only foster two theoretical inferences.

Determinism: that local anti-entropic effects are illusions generated by global entropy, and that human behaviors are merely the complex unwinding of physical systems to continually lower states of entropy, or…
Intentionalism: that human behavior is purposive anti-entropic action that only conforms to global entropy in the long run.

Most people adopt °2 because it more closely conforms to our self-perception (and honestly, because adopting °1 reduces us to the status of marionettes and begs every other philosophical question).
Now, people have always understood that °2 is not absolute: that our capacity for intention rests within physical systems that are not fully mastered or controlled. Thus we understand the concept of unintentional actions like accidents, physical needs and limitations, force majeure, demonic possession or saving grace, unintended consequences, etc. The problem is distinguishing between intentional acts and unintentional acts. This is usually addressed analytically as a matter of entropy: the more random and unproductive (entropic) the outcome of an act seems, the more we are inclined to believe it was unintentional. If a man falls off a cliff it seems senseless and we might write it off as an accident. But if the nephew who stands to inherit a million dollars was standing next to him at the time of the fall, we see a sense that raises the possibility it was intentional.

Entropy maps to the domain of natural causes. But it is not necessary to understand entropy to explain the human experience of volition or intentional action. Helmholtz provides the best generic explanation for moral perceptions which arise as the product of an unconscious process called unconscious inference. My theory is that humans map causes to distinctions (Man vs Nature; God vs Reality; and Conscious vs Unconscious) arising via a psychogenic process:
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/108493/do-descriptions-of-what-exist-map-to-causes-recognized-by-man-can-we-describe-c.

Interesting approach. How would one ascribe this entropy-based intentionality to, say, people rolling down a hill intentionally for fun? It seems to be both entropic and intentional.

@justhalf: People create situations of physical entropy so they can foster ordered (anti-entropic) internal states of relaxation, enjoyment, thrill, satisfaction, etc… It's a bit like hitting a reset button: take the accumulated mental entropy of daily living (generally lumped under the rubric 'stress') then physicalize and release it. And note that unlike rocks, people have to anti-entropically climb hills first in order to roll down them, and then they anti-entropically improve the experience with sleds, skis, go-carts, roller coasters, sky-diving, bungie-jumping…

@TedWrigley - I think philosophers and scientists coined the term emergence to discuss the mystery of how physical entropic systems (bodies and brains) come to recognize moral agents? Neither entropy nor emergence provide a physical explanation for folk psychology. The philosopher or scientist only holds that moral recognition ought to be consistent with models for natural sources of cause. But folk psychology begins in early life long before one has the adult reasoning capacity to contemplate entropy. Humans are born to recognize moral sources of cause. A natural cause means: non-moral.

@SystemTheory: Emergence has been kicked around a bit in discussions of human consciousness — I tend to think that way myself — but it hasn't been fleshed out or elaborated too much. Part of the problem is that the maths and sciences of it are too new, so there's nothing to build properly detailed analogies on. But in any case morality is a step up from intentional — all moral actions are by definition intentional, though the reverse is not true — and I didn't think we needed to bring that in here.

@TedWrigley - In thermodynamic analysis entropy always increases when specified for a system and its surroundings. We may assume that intentional minds only exist in humans and animals, and we may assume those minds are bound to the biological systems living on earth or in spacecraft inside a negative entropy region. We may assume the brain has unstable and stable energy and entropy states. Emergence is discussed actively in physics and philosophy because physical reduction models do not even apply to the laws of physics! Folk psychology is the domain where we experience intention AND physics!

@SystemTheory: I'm not seeing your point, or even quite following your phrasing. 'Folk psychology' obviously means something specific to you, but I'm not in on this jargon. You seem to be overestimating the impact and utility of the concept of emergence, but you're jumping between thermodynamics, moral theory, theory of being, 'folk psychology', etc, without drawing connection — or even making reasonable segues — or offering anything like a clear theoretical position. Right now these comments just seem like a jumble to me.  I'll have to read your answer and see if that clears it up, but…

@TedWrigley - Folk psychology is the general term for the idea that we experience mental states, and that we attribute mental states to animals and/or other humans. I don't know about your states of mind, their origin or evolution, but I was not born knowing any concepts of physics! I was born either with the innate or emergent capacity to recognize self and other humans as moral agents! I learned math and physics via social learning capacity in the context of folk psychology. Physics, chemistry, and biology all evoke emergent properties: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent/

@SystemTheory: Ah, I see. You're using 'folk psychology' to mean 'theory of mind'. Fair enough… I do feel like you're stretching the point, though. I mean, It's arguably possible to learn math, physics, or what you will without attributing mental states to any other person (and possibly not even to yourself). One could just see the text books as things that occur naturally, or as objects printed by mindless machines. There is certainly nothing in the subject matter of physics or math that requires an acknowledgement of other minds.

@SystemTheory: Further, there's a leap from having a 'theory of mind' that acknowledges others as conscious beings, and having a 'theory of moral agency' that attributes moral valuation to others. I think my dog has a 'mind', but I don't attribute moral agency to her. It seems to me that you're trying to juggle too many pins at once, and anyone who does that is bound to lose a few.

@TedWrigley - My dogs, parents, and teachers in grade school were not experts in comprehending entropy! However, my parents and teachers enabled me to learn how to encode and decode symbols in textbooks! Do you really think your counterfactual science fiction argument is sufficient to ignore the fact of social learning as the means to gain knowledge of how to read and decode what is written in textbooks? If so, it is poor philosophy and poor social science! But it is a clever argument! When Einstein calls Galileo the father of modern science he is evoking folk psychology and moral agency.

@SystemTheory: Well, that misses my point fairly effectively, and also gives me a sense of the language game (schema) you're invoking. So if you don't mind I'll step back from this conversation.

@TedWrigley - Actually the burden would be on you to reduce intentional states to anti-entropy in a more specific, rather than generic, statement of fact. Emergence is the word philosophers and scientists use when the whole seems to be greater than the sum of the parts or when qualia do not reduce to fundamental physical concepts. We have two domains of experience and you are only trying to reduce the one domain of intentional states to a generic concept of anti-entropy. Otherwise, your theory could explain how anti-entropy generates moral thoughts in humans but only non-moral states in dogs.

I began to actively contemplate this question more than thirty years ago while studying law after studying and working as an electrical engineer. The law, as a social institution concerned with the meaning of behavior, would be meaningless in the absence of what philosophers describe as folk psychology or mind reading. See this SEP article Folk Psychology as Mental Simulation:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/folkpsych-simulation/

The capacity for “mindreading” is understood in philosophy of mind and cognitive science as the capacity to represent, reason about, and respond to others’ mental states. Essentially the same capacity is also known as “folk psychology”, “Theory of Mind”, and “mentalizing”.


Mindreading is of crucial importance for our social life: our ability to predict, explain, and/or coordinate with others’ actions on countless occasions crucially relies on representing their mental states.

On the one hand it seems to be impossible to read the minds of others. Framing any observation from that mental perspective might cause one to conclude that it is not possible to determine whether an action is voluntary or not voluntary. But on the other hand it seems impossible for the self to navigate the world without attributing mental states to animals and other humans. Framing any observation from that mental perspective might cause one to conclude that it is impossible to stop attributing mental states to animals and persons.
I automatically infer that people and animals express their will via voluntary actions; and I would consciously infer that people and animals in fact experience their will similar to my own. My concept will is taken from conversations with my late professor for Torts and Legal Philosophy, Hugh Gibbons. Some of his papers are published here on Biology of Law: https://www.biologyoflaw.org/Downloads/index.htm.
Hugh argues, in a footnote of Justifying Law, that the human will is based on the experience of oneself as a cause of perceptions, which is derived from the concepts called Perceptual Control Theory (PCT). Another term for the self as a biological control system with feedback between action and perception is the field of cybernetics. The video below gives an overview of Perceptual Control Theory. The presenter, a psychologist, calls this a theory of behavior:
https://youtu.be/Lj18bYqm4ZQ
The basic idea is that when a person, for example, sips tea, this behavior means that the person makes efforts to control their own perceptions.
In said footnote Hugh describes the will as a statement: I am the cause of desired perceptions. There is a feedback loop of present perceptions, a desire to change perceptions, actions to change perceptions, and evaluation of the outcome of those actions. In this context one experiences the will of the self as a cause of changing perceptions. Then the will of each person is the assumption that others are expressing their volitional or intentional will when they undertake actions arising in each other's perceptions.
Hermann von Helmholtz did research on human vision and perception. In a simplified experiment go out some night and put your thumb up to obscure the image of the full moon. This proves that you thumb is larger than the moon in the 2D field of visual perception. However, in the 3D perceptions of reality we infer that the moon is very large compared to our thumb and moves at a speed around the earth in orbit. The understanding of the moon's orbit is a concept built up from many perceptions and concepts developed by many scientists over time. But in daily life we sense the 3D position and speed of objects without using conscious inference. Helmholtz argues that such perceptions arise as the product of an unconscious process and he calls that general cognitive process an unconscious inference. The recognition of the will of others seems to arise because we experience the will of the self and then we infer via unconscious and conscious inference that actions may or may not be driven by will of another under relevant conditions. In other words, we judge the volitional, intentional, and willful acts as the product of a process having attributes of unconscious and conscious inference.

@Lowri When Galileo describes speed and acceleration as physical observations are these observations derived from voluntary acts of will or are the physical observations totally involuntary? I would argue that it is a circular argument to try to get the human will out of the feedback loop that we call making physical observations. We build machines with sensors and cybernetic feedback control systems that operate on physical observations. Some scientists argue that the physical systems are observers. But when physical systems fail the engineers may be blamed for negligence.

You must have an interesting mental life: I'm an engineer and my father was a lawyer, and we could never understand each other :-)

@ScottRowe - In the past I had much more capacity to speak the language of engineers or lawyers. But then, at age thirty, God quickened me with such dramatic intensity unlike anything one could describe. The literary device called hyperbole exists to communicate the intensity of such drama. In the domain of such drama one can fight a bear at the age of three; steal fire from the gods; smite the wicked with the jawbone of an ass (without actually harming anyone in the world of human affairs); pray, Father forgive them for they know not what they do; weep over Jerusalem; via ones' imagination.

Studying law and working as an electrical engineer? Waauw, cool :).

Is coerced action voluntary, or involuntary?

@RonJohn - Informally coerced action is a voluntary action undertaken due to duress against one's will. The coerced action is not a desired perception of the person who undertakes the action. My Legal Philosophy professor Hugh Gibbons describes law as the justified use of coercion. He describes the will as an I-statement: I am the cause of desired perceptions. According to Gibbons the will, or experience of self as cause of desired perceptions, is subject to internal limitations and external constraints. Coercion is an external constraint on one's will imposed by the will of another person.

"voluntary action ... against one's will" sounds like an oxymoron.  After all, it's not voluntary if done under duress.  I didn't voluntarily take nasty medicine when I was a child, and shopkeepers didn't voluntarily pay protection money to gangsters.

@RonJohn - I agree with you coerced action is considered involuntary under the traditional view of the law. On the other hand, there is a potential semantic problem in the fact patterns and use of language in the context of law. Civil negligence or involuntary crimes often arise when the defendant engages in a voluntary undertaking, a pattern of conduct, that causes harm to (the will of) another person, even though the defendant did not consciously intend to cause such harm. If the undertaking was done under coercion then it would be considered involuntary. Involuntary is polysemic in the law.

It depends on the action performed and the familiarity with such actions - and their likely consequences - by the observer.
There is also the emotional spectrometer of the observer - certain actions evoke unmistakable emotions in the active parties and these are strong enough to be felt by the observer.
For example, a peeping Tom in the bushes at a lovers' lane may observe what he (from experience) recognizes to be the conduct of a molester or rapist as compared to that of a person with amorous intent.

Driving your car, a stone hits your front window. -- Was that event a purposeful, voluntary event? It's strange to call a physical event "purposeful" or "voluntary". Being voluntary is not a physical property; we cannot measure it with physical detectors (at least not with currently available ones). Events just happen. But we ask for explanations. Was the stone hitting the window purposeful in the sense that some agent, on purpose, with the deliberate aim of hitting your driving car, threw a stone at it and succeeded in its aim? It's very well possible that this was the case. At least, it might be possible, depending on further circumstances; i.e. depending on a more detailed description of what happened.
Purposes, goals, aims, the will to do something -- all these are attributed to agents in order to explain the behavior and actions of those agents. How do we know that those attributions are correct -- in the case of other humans?
How do we know the attributions we make for our own actions and behaviors are correct? We know they are (probably) correct when they explain and integrate more available data and observations.
(1) The stone might be a pebble throws by a few bored teenagers from a bridge. They just wanted to have a bit of fun; see if they could startle the driver, perhaps. If so, we can predict they will be shocked when they then witness a fatal car crash. (2) The stone might be a brick thrown by some crazy assassin. That person will not be shocked by the car crash, since that's just what they aimed for. (3) A military autonomous drone, out of regular munition, released a stone in order to hit the car in which you, a terrorist, are trying to flee. Should we say that in this case, since the drone is just a machine, the action was not purposeful? Is it necessary to have mental states just like humans have in order to be able to exhibit purposeful behavior?

It is impossible to observe something that does not happen. “Voluntary” implies the idea of a subject, but the notion of a subject in an immaterial sense is not defined. A subject may be defined as the body, but clearly, anything caused by the body cannot be voluntary.
So there must be a way to differentiate between whether or not an action caused by the body is voluntary or not. But what is the difference? Both have the same kinds of preceding physical causes. There is nothing fundamentally different happening in a “voluntary” action except the fact that one, in consciousness, has the added thought of “I did this” along with the actual action being done.

This question is unanswerable:
Ηow can we identify an actually voluntary or involuntary action as such with a significant degree of certainty? Sometimes, the person him/herself can't. There are so many accidental movements and even actions done mechanically that the person himself is not aware of.
But this question is also meaningless:
Why would one want to identify every human action as voluntary or not? What's the purpose of it?
Finally, "voluntary" and "purposeful" are two different things, not necessarily compatible with each other. E.g. I find this question not purposeful, yet I certainly cannot say it is also involuntary.

It's like the old comedy skit where someone starts slapping another person who tells them to stop, and they say they don't have free will and can't help doing it.



If you familiarize yourself with the Greek word 'hypostasis' it's describing the underlying structure on which all of reality exists. Human beings, rocks, precious metals, light and rain are all examples of the same thing. Everything in existence, from a concept to an apartment building, is actually all one energy that has been manifested at varying densities through different conditioning processes. I say all of that to say this; Everything is willed from somewhere...
Using your example, for a more acceptable idea, someone raises their hand. You can physically observe whether the action is willed and intentional by watching the manner in which they move. For a person to lift their arm up requires an intention, which we know logically. But by observing it, anybody who's been around people throughout their life naturally develops faculties that identify subtleties in movement and body language. So it's something you can see and know without necessarily knowing how you know.
If that same person wasn't a real person, a computer program for instance, and they raised their hand, were they not programmed to raise their hand? It was the will of the one who designed it to do so, presumably...

I've created computer programs which people then used in ways I never anticipated. I am sure that people find novel ways to use a wooden spoon. I started a car with a pencil once. But 'nature' creates new chemical compounds also, where is the will in that?

You created programs and people chose to use them for ways YOU didn't intend. But it was SOMEBODY'S will to use it differently. And as far as chemical compounds? It was nature's will... Just because it's a process that doesn't match up with your own, or your expectation of what it should be, doesn't invalidate it. The evolutionary process is the product of intelligent design. Do you disagree that human beings were intelligently designed?

Several people I know have had cancer. My computer seems more intelligently designed than that.

It is not impossible to physically observe a voluntary action.
There are two options:

The action is a physical reaction to a physical cause (involuntary).
The action is a mentally caused proaction (voluntary).

If no physical cause can be observed, then the action must be voluntary.
